# CSS position element above bootstrap selectpicker

Tags: css, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a `bootstrap selectpicker` and a `chatbox` on the same page. The `selectpicker` is always above the `chatbox` like in the picture below:

[image]

I tried setting the chatbox `z-index` to 999999 and changing `margin` to negative (`-90px`) like indicated in other SO posts. But does not seem to work.

How can i fix this?

**Chat box log css**

```
padding: 3px;
height: 250px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
background: #fff;
position: relative;
margin: -90px auto;
z-index: 9000000;
```

**JSfiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/iliadeviatov/s5tmy4z7/6/

Comment: What code do you  have so far?

Comment: please post your code here

Comment: can post the bootstrap selectpicker css, but it is standard

Comment: And your HTML? Can you provide a Fiddle?

Comment: okay will build one up

Comment: i added a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Z-index should work. Please note that **z-index is always inherited from the parent if it is set**, so just try increasing the z-index of the parent element of the chat box and see if that solves it.

Comment: The chat box container does not have any z-index set. So if i change it to anything above 0, it is displayed correctly above the bootrstap selectpicker. So your answer, led me to the correct solution. Please add it to your answer so i can mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you make your z-index important.
for example `z-index: 1001 !important`. This fixed the problem for me when I ecountered it.